# Refer to an element in a clojure map from within the same map?

Tags: clojure

How can I refer to an element in a clojure map from another element?

```
{:num (calculate-num-function)
 :sometext "Hello"
 :double-num (* 2 :num)}   ;; Is something like this possible?
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? why isn't this an option: `(let [num 1000] {:num num :sometext "hello" :double-num (* 2 num)})` ?

Comment: in this case you can't reference another value, since it hasn't been read and evaluated yet. You have to create a map first, and then use it's values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(let [m {:num (calculate-num-function) :sometext "Hello"}
      m2 (assoc m :double-num (* 2 (:num m)))}] ... )
```

Would be one way to do it.

Another:

```
(let [num (calculate-num-function)
      m {:num num :sometext "Hello" :double-num (* 2 num)}] ...)
```

Otherwise, no, you can't do what you want, nor is there a need to do so.